# Module not Found : Can't resolve './utils'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, popper.js, react-popper

```
- error ./node_modules/react-popper/lib/esm/Popper.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve './utils'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/react-popper/lib/esm/index.js
./node_modules/reactstrap/esm/Dropdown.js
./node_modules/reactstrap/esm/index.js
./src/components/widget/StatsWidget.js
./src/pages/dashboard.js
```

I keep getting this error in my code when I try to open my website. I tried installing `react-popper` and `Popper.js` modules and I also tried installing utils but nothing seems to work. Let me know how I can resolve of this error.

Comment: may be use a different version of react-popper. From the error code, what I understand is in the esm build of popper, it can't locate ./utils folder. May be using a most downloaded version of react-popper would resolve this